# Как определить какой элемент развернули в TreeDateGrid? С# Avalonia

Tags: c#, treeview, avalonia

Я создаю диспетчер файлов, и пока что разбираюсь с папками. Я работаю с контролом TreeDataGrid (из avalonia). TreeDataGrid это комбинация DataGrid и TreeView.
Папки хранятся в коллекции такого типа:

```
public class Folder
{
    public Folder(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        
    }
    public Folder(DirectoryInfo di)
    {
        Name = di.Name;
        
    }


    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Folder> ChildrenFolder { get;  } = new();
}
```

Но собирать полное дерево выходит очень долго. Я хочу подгружать его динамически. Как мне узнать какой элемент разворачивает пользователь?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда нажимаешь на значок, который я выделила синим, папка разворачивается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я могу получать выделенный элемент , но я не знаю как мне это может помочь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы знаете как это можно сделать для treeView,то тоже пишите. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я посмотрел документацию TreeView Авалонии. Странно, что нет события наподобие Expanded. / https://stackoverflow.com/a/73064167/5045688 - что-то в этом духе нужно

Comment: Спасибо, у меня почему то все еще не получается динамически подгружать папки(

Comment: У вас получилось? У меня сейчас такая же проблема